# bootstrap set button to stay left

Tags: responsive

I have the following Problem. I designed a Website with and responsable Navigation Bar. Here is the code:

```
                        <div class="menu">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-left" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation" ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="it-service.html">IT-Service</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="buero.html">BÃ¼ro-Service</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="contacts.html">Kontakt</a></li>                        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

when I look at it with an mobile device the "Kontakt" Button is fixed on the right side if i set "Büro-Service" active.

Here is what I found in my css file:

```css
.menu {
 font-size:14px;
 float:right;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:600; 
}

.menu ul.nav-tabs li {
 color:#000; 
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 line-height: 1.42857143;
 border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
 border-radius:0;
 color:#000;
 border-top:0;
 border-right:0;
 border-left:0; 
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
  border-color: #eee #eee #50c0e9;
   color: #50c0e9;
  border-radius:0;
  background-color:#f9f9f9;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #50c0e9;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  cursor:pointer;  
}
```

and here are the media queries that i found:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape), screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  /**
       * Remove all paddings around the image on small screen
       */
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-image-holder {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile img.mfp-img {
    padding: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-figure small {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: auto;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; }
    .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-bottom-bar:empty {
      padding: 0; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-counter {
    right: 5px;
    top: 3px; }
  .mfp-img-mobile .mfp-close {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0; } }

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .mfp-arrow {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    transform: scale(0.75); }
  .mfp-arrow-left {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
    transform-origin: 0; }
  .mfp-arrow-right {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100%; }
  .mfp-container {
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px; } }

.mfp-ie7 .mfp-img {
  padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-bottom-bar {
  width: 600px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-container {
  padding: 0; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-content {
  padding-top: 44px; }
.mfp-ie7 .mfp-close {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 0; }
```

Can anyone help me in this case?

Best regards,

Felix

Comment: Can you add your CSS too?

Comment: I´m a completly new in bootstrap and there are 15 css files. Can you give me a keyword so i can fetch the right one?

Comment: I searched in all Files and added what i found

Comment: There's likely a media query that is styling the contact button to be positioned to the right - can you locate the media queries?

Comment: thanks for the fast response and help! Do you mean this stuff here:     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Nope, it will be something like `@media screen and (min-width:....`....

Comment: Thanks Stuard, i added what i found in the imported css files

Comment: Likely to use rows and columns classes instead of own style

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. Can you tell how i could do this?